# Tizen device manager do not see my Samsung s9+

Tags: android, mobile, adb, samsung-mobile, tizen

ADB can see my phone... 
(so usb enabled, device authorized - all good)
but ! in tizen devices manager: nothing ... 
what to check and which problem to search ?

Comment: This may be required. ACL (Application Compatibility Layer) to run android app on tizen. Google it.

Comment: just to clarify : listed on ADB, listed on SDB, i can see my device in Visual studio - when connected - to run it there : when try - get VS error(build successfull) :Value cannot be null. Parameter Name: Input. if try sdb install - another error... so  bottom  line can run only on Emulator... cannot deploy and phone is not listed in Tizens device manager (in Xamarin tools- all good...)

Answer (score 1):

For all who may face it as i did :
Samsung S9+ is NOT using Tizen :) just plain Android...
so it cannot apply Tizen template ... just ordinary Xamarin app will work...